# List of dict of dict to pandas pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I want to convert future_df in a data Frame:

```
item1 = {'name': 'A', 'parameters': [{'Parameter': 'P1', 'Value': 0.0},{'Parameter': 'P2', 'Value': 0.4}]}
item2 = {'name': 'B', 'parameters': [{'Parameter': 'P1', 'Value': 3},{'Parameter': 'P2', 'Value': 7}]}
future_df = [item1, item2]
```

I achieve this with the ugly following lines:

```
df = {}
for item in future_df:
    dic = {key['Parameter']:key['Value'] for key in item['parameters']}
    df[future_df['name']] = dic
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values(), index=df.keys())
```

I know that this is very hardcoded solution, and there has to be a more clean elegant one. I guess that json_normalize function could be helpfull but I did not find the way how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically a one-liner:

```
print (pd.DataFrame({i["name"]: {v["Parameter"]: v["Value"] for v in i["parameters"]}
                     for i in future_df}).T)

    P1   P2
A  0.0  0.4
B  3.0  7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is necessary nicer if you write a function to pivot it wide first:

```
def ToDF(item):
    x = pd.DataFrame(item['parameters'])
    x.insert(0,"name",item['name'])
    return x.pivot_table(columns="Parameter",values="Value",index="name")
```

Then concat like this:

```
df = pd.concat([ToDF(i) for i in future_df])
df

Parameter   P1   P2
name               
A          0.0  0.4
B          3.0  7.0
```